# Contributions and Events

Tags: civievent, contributions, links

I have been trying to find a way on how to divide one fundraising event into three parts - because our event was supporting three different initiatives and we want to know which contact supported which initiative within the event, and how much money they donated for every initiative.

It is also important for us to create a link that includes all the three initiatives because the fundraising is to be continued online - any suggestions on how to do that? The link will then be sent out through a mailing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Civi?

Answer (score 1):

Rereading - unsure if my other answer helps at all but will leave it for now. Price Sets may be more what you are after. I set one up [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/price/field?reset=1&action=browse&sid=9&new=1) which you can see in action [here](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1)

(note the above links will only be good till the site refreshes- but make a Price Set using "text/numeric", "Price = 1.00" and do not show 'Display Amount' - that will give you 3 fields where a person can enter the amount they want to give to each of the 3 parts - then set your Contribution Page to use the Price Set constructed above)

You can't use Campaigns on a per line item afaik so not sure that other suggestion helps but I think for reporting you can get what you need from  eileen@fuzion's Extended Report https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport which offers "Price Set Line Items" reports. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Unsure how much this helps as your refer to Events, but not necessarily CiviEvent.

Anyhow, Campaigns is a civi function that can run across multiple entities. Hence you can create a Campaign for the 'event' and then have multiple CiviEvents, Contribution Pages, CiviMailings etc all related to that Campaign to make it easier to report against